# Why after parsing template ,my modals doesn't work

Tags: django, bootstrap-modal

My reply comment modal doesn't work after I parsed the templates(navigation,footer,base).But if I put them all in same page (not parsing) is working.If I parse them,the modal reply (id="modal-reply") doesnt't work.Can anyone help me?What should I do to fix that?

```
commentsAdmin.html

    {% extends 'AdminTemplates/baseAdmin.html' %}
    {% load static %}
        {% block contentAdmin %}
      
      <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <!-- Breadcrumbs-->
          <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li class="breadcrumb-item">
              <a href="{% url 'indexAdmin' %}">Anasayfa</a>
            </li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Yorumlar</li>
          </ol>
            <div class="box_general">
                <!-- <div class="header_box">
                    <h2 class="d-inline-block">Yorumlar</h2>
                    <div class="filter">
                        <select name="orderby" class="selectbox">
                            <option value="Any time">Any time</option>
                            <option value="Latest">Latest</option>
                            <option value="Oldest">Oldest</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div> -->
                <div class="list_general reviews">
                    <ul>
    
                        <!-- {{stars}}
                         -->
                        {% for comment in comments %}
                            <li>
                                <span>{{comment.created_date}}</span>
                                <span class="rating">
    
                                 
                                 {% for star in comment.getStar %}
                                 <i class="fa fa-fw fa-star yellow"></i>
                                 {% endfor %}
                                 {% for star in comment.getNoneStar %}
                                 <i class="fa fa-fw fa-star"></i>
                                 {% endfor %}
                                 </span>
                                     
                                    
                                <figure><img src="{{comment.course.image.url}}" alt=""></figure>
                                <h4>{{comment.course.title}}</h4>
                                <p>{{comment.comment}}</p>
                                <p class="inline-popups"><a href="#modal-reply" data-effect="mfp-zoom-in" class="btn_1 gray"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-reply"></i> Reply to this review</a></p>
                            </li>
                        {% endfor %}
                       
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            
          </div>
          <!-- /container-fluid-->
        </div>
    
        {% endblock contentAdmin %}
   
        {% block scriptsAdmin %}
    
        <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript-->
        <script src="{% static 'assetsAdmin/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'assetsAdmin/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js' %}"></script>
        
        <!-- Core plugin JavaScript-->
        <script src="{% static 'assetsAdmin/vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js' %}"></script>
        <!-- Page level plugin JavaScript-->
        <script src="{% static 'assetsAdmin/vendor/chart.js/Chart.js' %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'assetsAdmin/vendor/datatables/jquery.dataTables.js' %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'assetsAdmin/vendor/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.js' %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'assetsAdmin/vendor/jquery.selectbox-0.2.js' %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'assetsAdmin/vendor/retina-replace.min.js' %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'assetsAdmin/vendor/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js' %}"></script>
        <!-- Custom scripts for all pages-->
        <script src="{% static 'assetsAdmin/js/admin.js' %}"></script>
        <!-- Custom scripts for this page-->
    {% endblock scriptsAdmin %}
```

my footer file

```
<footer class="sticky-footer">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="text-center">
        <small>Copyright ©</small>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
  <!-- Scroll to Top Button-->
  <a class="scroll-to-top rounded" href="#page-top">
    <i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i>
  </a>



  
    <!-- Reply to review popup -->
<div id="modal-reply" class="white-popup mfp-with-anim mfp-hide" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="small-dialog-header">
        <h3>Reply to review</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="message-reply margin-top-0">
        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea cols="40" rows="3" class="form-control"></textarea>
        </div>
        <button class="btn_1">Reply</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what does "parsing" refer to? Does it mean including a Django template?

Comment: Yes, it refers django templates.

Comment: So your modal does not work if you're using `{% include modal.html %}` as opposed to directly having it in your page? Did I understand you correctly? Can you post the code that does not work?